# upgrade specific package yarn lock after Dependabot alert on github

Tags: git, github, npm, yarnpkg

I have this error on github :

[image: name]

I didn't find any solution. Did I have to update manually in yarn.lock package the version of Logkitty and after that, commit and push? Or a commande exist to upgrade specific package?

Why this error appear in yarn.lock and not to package.json?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears in yarn.lock and not in package.json because logkitty was not a direct dependency of your project, but rather a dependency of one of your package.json's dependencies.

you could merge the pull request.